# WPF Mixing Bound and Fixed text in a TextBox

Tags: .net, wpf, text, binding, textbox

I have the following code to display a clients age.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtClientAge" Text="{Binding Path=ClientAge}" />
```

However, instead of just displaying just the number, I want to prefix it with the text "Age " and suffix it with the text " yrs" so it is effectively becomes "Age 36 yrs"

I can achieve this with a horizontal StackPanel and 3 Textboxes, but is there a much simpler method that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you want "age " and " yrs" parts to be editable? I.e. should user be allowed to type "age 40 yrs" (or perhaps also simply "40") into the textbox in its entirety, and have it parsed correctly?

Comment: In any case, if you only have a single such textbox in your application (i.e. no need for it to be reusable), the StackPanel + 2 TextBlocks + TextBox solution is going to be the simplest.

Comment: It's just to be used as readonly, no updating required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the age value to be editable, in WPF 4.0 the Text property of Run will be bindable, this probably doesn't help you right now unless you are using the pre-release but you will be able to do something like the following:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtClientAge" >
    <Run Text="Age "/><Run Text="{Binding Path=ClientAge}"/><Run Text=" Yrs"/>
</TextBlock>
```

**UPDATE** Heres another alternative to the format string solution that will work but is not particularly pretty (in fact its quite hacky). Use the following converter on the binding (assuming ClientAge property is of type int):

```
public class AgeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string age = value.ToString();
        return "Age " + age + " years";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string age = value as string;
        return Int32.Parse(age.Replace("Age ", " ").Replace(" years", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, that was the sort of thing I was looking for but as you say, it's not quite with us yet! I might have to adopt a long winded approach for now until WPF 4.0 is with us.

Comment: Nice bit of lateral thinking mate. I'm currently enjoying using Converters for all sorts of things so your approach really appeals. Thanks for that!

Comment: Yeah the ConvertBack is the part I don't like, but since its a readonly situation that is not going to be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

This is quite an old question, but I think this is the current best solution (if you want to edit the text).

You can do it with an `InlineUIContainer` in a `TextBlock` with a nested `Textbox`.

Note: I've used `BaselineAlignment="Center"` to align the components. You can also add positive or negative margins to the `TextBox` as necessary. Also I set the border of the `TextBox` as transparent to make it look like part of the `TextBlock` even though it is editable and selectable.

```
<TextBlock Foreground="SteelBlue">
    <Run Text="Package Barcode:" FontWeight="Bold" BaselineAlignment="Center"/>
    <InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Margin="2,0,0,0" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding BarcodeNumber}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0"/>
    </InlineUIContainer>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: yes i realize the original questioner ultimately wanted the 'age' to be read only - but this is an answer to the question as asked :-)

Comment: This is quite an old answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a property in the class you're binding too that creates the text string you'd like to display.

There's also the StringFormat route:

```
<textblock text="{Binding Path=mydate, StringFormat=d}"/>
```

You can hack constants into the formatting string.

I prefer the property method.

Comment: This is essentially modifying your model to be view-aware - a very bad idea from design perspective.

Comment: +1 for StringFormat. Agree with @Pavel - don't create a property with this text in it.

Comment: If you really want to do this right then the text doesn't belong in the view either. It needs to be in a resource area selected by the presentation layer based on your current culture setting. Which is why all my stuff comes from presenter properties.

Answer (score 1):

This is like a previous answer - (but they're all with Texblocks... so here a Textbox version), I also wanted to show the Multibinding approach. To get a Texbox to do what you want, you can use the following code:

```
<TextBox>
 <TextBox.Text>
   <MultiBinding StringFormat="Age {0} yrs and {1} months">
     <Binding Path="Years" />
     <Binding Path="Months" />
   </MultiBinding>
 </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

It may be useful if you want to make your text selectable so a user can copy the code.